# If $X=\{0,1\}$ then for any set $A,$ prove that $|X^A|= |P(A)|.$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

**Claim:** If $X=\{0,1\}$ then for any set $A,$ prove that $|X^A|= |P(A)|$ (where, $P(A)$ denotes the power set of $A$).

The proof given was :

> If $A=\phi$ then $P(A)=\{\phi\}$ and $X^A$ contains the function $\phi$ and so $|P(A)|=|X^A|.$
>
> Let $A\neq \phi.$ Define a mapping, $\theta:P(A)\to X^A$ as follows:
>
> If $B\subset A$ then, $\psi_B:A\to X$ is
>
> $$\psi_B(x)=1\space \text{if}\space x\in B$$
>
> $$\psi_B(x)=0\space \text{if}\space x\notin B.$$
>
> Clearly, $\psi_B\in X^A.$
>
> We define $\theta(B)=\psi_B,$ then $\theta$ is well-defined for if $B_1=B_2,$ then $\psi_{B_1}=\psi_{B_2}$ i.e $\theta(B_1)=\theta(B_2).$
>
> $\theta$ is one-one for if $B_1\neq B_2$ then $\psi_{B_1}\neq \psi_{B_2}.$
>
> To show, $\theta$ is surjective, let $f\in X^A.$ Then define $B=\{x\in A|f(\alpha)=1\}.$
>
> So, $\theta(B)=\psi_B=f.$ Thus, $\theta$ is a bijection between $X^A$ and $P(A).$

---

*Notation: If S is a set, then by $|S|$ I mean, cardinality of the set $S$. The notation $X^A$ was unknown to me. I found out that $X^A$ is a standard notation, which is used to denote "*the set of all functions from $A$ to $X.$*"*

Even then, I find this proof, unnecessarily lengthy and so, I attempted to devise an alternative proof which might be simpler. Here it is:

We start by proving a lemma that $|A^B|=|A|^{|B|}.$

$A^B$ is the set of all functions from $B$ to $A.$ The set  $B$ has $|B|$ number of elements and each such element (say,) $b$ can have $|A|$ number of output values for $f(b)$ under a function say, $f.$ So, the total number of $f's$ possible are, $\underbrace{|A|\times|A|\times\cdots\times |A|}_{\text{|B| times}}=|A|^{|B|},$ which is in fact equal to $|A^B|.$

---

If $X=\{0,1\}$ then using the above lemma, we have, $$X^A=|X|^{|A|}=2^{|A|}\tag 1.$$

Also, we know that $|P(B)|,$ i.e the number of subsets of $B$ is $2^{|B|}.$ Thus, $|P(A)|=2^{|A|}\tag 2.$

Hence, using the equalities in $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have, $|P(A)|=|X^A|=2^{|A|},$ which is what we were required to prove.

---

However, I feel that my alternate proof is only valid, if $A,B$ (in the lemma) and $A$ (in the main proof,) are finite sets. Is this a limitation of my arguments ? If this is the case, I want an elaborate explanation why it's not true for infinite sets in general.

If my arguments, are valid with respect to  the above (mentioned) respects, any suggestions, to improve this proof, would be appreciated.

Comment: You proved nothing, the problem asks to prove that $2^{|A|}=|P(A)|$, which you have not done.

Comment: @VivaanDaga Sorry, but I can't agree with you unless you are specific, in your reasonings. I showed that the cardinality of $P(A)$ is the same as the cardinality of $X^A$ by calculating each one, separately. This was my idea (in case it's unclear).

Comment: @VivaanDaga is correct. You haven’t proven that $2^{|A|} = |P(A)|$ which is what you are being asked to show

Comment: The only thing that you have proven is that $2^X  = |2^X|=|2|^{|X|}$ but you haven’t found any relation from $2^X$ to the power set

Comment: @FD_bfa Sorry, but I would again request you to elaborate. It is probable, that my proof might be/is faulty. But, I have edited my post, to avoid any sort of miscommunication. I hope this might make thinks clear.

Comment: The mistake you are making is that you assume $|P(B)| = 2^{|B|}$. You can’t assume this. This is what you are supposed to be trying to prove in the first place

Comment: @FD_bfa So, my understanding in the OP i.e "However, I feel that my alternate proof is only valid, if $A,B$ (in the lemma) and $A$ (in the main proof,) are finite sets" is correct? The properties which are true in case of $|A|,|B|$ being real numbers (or, in other words when $A,B$  being finite sets)  is not true when $|A|,|B|$ are not real numbers. The thing is: When $A,B$ are infinite sets, then $|A|,|B|$ are not real numbers and so, the properties of real numbers which we used in the proof and lemma is not valid.

Comment: This is a limitation of the way you have proven the lemma, but in general $|A^B| = |A|^{|B|}$ even for infinite sets. The central issue is that you need to show that the cardinality of the power set (set of all subsets of $A$) is equal to the cardinality of the set of all functions from $A$ to $\{0,1 \}$ which you haven't currently shown

Comment: @FD_bfa In the answer, you said, that the way I have proven the lemma is correct, but here you say it's not i.e has a limitation , if I understand you correctly. Can you please clarify this issue? +1 from me, for a good answer, in general!

Comment: Technically $|X^A| = |X|^{|A|}$ is true by definition so you don't actually need a proof (this is one of the fundamental rules of cardinal arithmetic). But your proof attempt is a good intuition for how to think about it. The Wikipedia page summarises the fundamental rules of cardinal arithmetic quite well (including cardinal exponentiation - which is what you are using) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_arithmetic These rules are true without needing any proofs because this is just the way that we define the cardinal arithmetic operations

Comment: @FD_bfa Thanks for the information!

Comment: The book "Introduction to Set Theory"  by Karel Hrbáček and Thomas Jech is one of the best rigorous introductory set theory books that I've ever come across. So if you're interested in exploring these sorts of questions and concepts further, I'd recommend having a read through that (I believe there is a PDF made available online) - be careful to read the introductory book though, they also have other set theory publications which are targeted at experts in the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red step is where your proof breaks down:

$$X^A=|X|^{|A|}=2^{|A|} \color{red}{= |P(A)|}$$

The first two steps are fine (your lemma shows the first equality and the second equality holds by applying the definition $\{0,1 \} = 2$). However, nowhere in your proof do you justify the why the red part should hold. If you assume this, then you're correct that the claim can be shown much more directly. However, to prove the claim properly, we typically don't assume that $|P(A)| = 2^{|A|}$ and so we need a bit more work to show that this is actually the case.

We usually just state the $|P(A)| = 2^{|A|}$ without much thought. But when we are asked to prove a claim like this, we need to justify this step. Remember that since the power set is the set of all subsets of $A$, it is not necessarily obvious that the cardinality of this set should be equal to $2^A$ (the set of all functions from $A$ to $2$).

Equally, you are also right that your proof of the lemma does not generalise to infinite cardinalities (although this is a fairly straightforward fix as [the lemma holds for all sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_exponentiation) without the need for a proof since it is true by definition). The fundamental issue that you will run into is the one above. This will always mean that the proof takes longer and you won't really be able to get it much shorter than the one that you presented above without making the proof harder to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Send $f \in X^{A}$ to $\{a\in A\mid f(a)=1\}\in P(A)$. Just show that this map is an isomorphism, which is not hard at all.